# Ejb Class File Update Issue

Tags: linux, weblogic12c

I am using weblogic12C with Linux server.I am changing one class in ejb jar and updating the ear from weblogic.But my updated code is not executing.I have tried starting server many times from weblogic.I have rename cache and temp folder and start server again.But still same.Don know from where it is picking old code.

Please help.

Comment: Update your application with the admin console to ask the server to load the new version of your application.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel,I have updated from web logic admin console only.In development i have windows server +weblogic there it is working,means changes are reflecting.But UAT we have weblogic+linux.Here changes are not reflecting.

Answer (score 0):

I had  this problem ,you can stop the server and delete cache ,tmp,data folder safely and then start the server the problem must be solved.